# Замена значений списка списков на список

Tags: python, список

Есть такой список:

```
[(1, 11, u'a', u'w'), 
(1, 24, u'пd', u'fпр'), 
(1, 44, u'dы', u'fав'), 
(2, 66, u'аd', u'f'), 
(2, 24, u'd', u'f' ), 
(4, 5, u'd', u'sd')]
```

Нужно заменить первые значения: 1,1,1,2,2,4. Есть соответственный список других значений:

```
l2 = [12, 48, 99]
```

Хотелось бы получить:

```
[(12, 11, u'a', u'w'), 
(12, 24, u'пd', u'fпр'), 
(12, 44, u'dы', u'fав'), 
(48, 66, u'аd', u'f'), 
(48, 24, u'd', u'f' ), 
(99, 5, u'd', u'sd')]
```

Здесь данные могут быть представлены, без разницы, и в списках, и в словарях.

Comment: @rss, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) может быть использован, чтобы сгруппировать кортежи в списке с одинаковыми первыми элементами:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = map(itemgetter(1), groupby(L, key=itemgetter(0)))
L = [(new_value,) + item[1:] 
     for group, new_value in zip(grouped, l2)
     for item in group]
```

#### [Результат](http://ideone.com/7RCya7)

```
[(12, 11, 'a', 'w'),
 (12, 24, 'пd', 'fпр'),
 (12, 44, 'dы', 'fав'),
 (48, 66, 'аd', 'f'),
 (48, 24, 'd', 'f'),
 (99, 5, 'd', 'sd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в списке `l2` всего три значения, а в большом списке 6. Не понятно, по какому принципу Вы меняете. В случае когда, в обоих списках одинаковое кол-во элементов, то можно написать:
`L = [tuple(l2[i] + list(l[i]) for i in range(len(L))]`

Comment: Возможно, имеется в виду, что 1 заменить на 12, 2 на 48, 4 на 99.